# unknown type name PtrJogo

Tags: c, struct, typedef

stackDynamic.h

```
#include "TreasureHunt.h"
typedef PtrJogo TypeElement;

typedef struct Node *PtrNode;
struct Node{
    TypeElement *ptrElement;
    PtrNode ptrPrev;
}Node;

typedef struct stack{
    PtrNode top;
}Stack;

typedef struct Stack *PtrStack;
```

So this is the header of a generic stack i'm trying to use on a project.

the line

```
  #include "TreasureHunt.h"
```

include the file where the type PtrJogo is defined, which is the type i pretend to place inside of the stack. This is the structs defined there:

TreasureHunt.h

```
#include "stackDynamic.h"    

typedef struct Jogo *PtrJogo;
typedef struct Jogo{
    PtrLocation ptrLocalizacaoAtual;
    PtrMapa ptMapa;
    PtQueue movimentos;
    PtrStack stackUndo;

}Jogo;
```

whenever i  compile, i receive an error on the following line:

```
 typedef PtrJogo TypeElement;
```

the error is:   unknown type name 'PtrJogo'

i have been using this type in a couple other files with no problem , but it doesn't work with the stack. i'm pretty sure it's a really simple error that i'm overlooking.

Comment: Don't `typedef` pointers! And re-`typedef` types only if there is a very good reason. Your code already looks pretty obfuscated.

Comment: @Olaf really? is there a specific reason for it? because we have been doing it in pretty much every class(suggested by the teachers). what can i do as an alternative then?

Comment: You have `typedef struct Jogo *PtrJogo;`, then `typedef TypeElement PtrJogo;`, and then in your struct you have `TypeElement *ptrElement;`. This means that `ptrElement` is a `struct Jogo **` (double pointer).

Comment: You already fell into the trap of over-`typedef`ing and obfuscated code for the pointers. Such code is hard to read, because you always have to know the exact semantics of the `typedef`ed names - or use a distinct naming scheme, which is longer than the `*` for the pointer which is also understood by every C programmer. C does not use compatibility by name, but by real type. Classes are not real life and - sadly - many teachers have no idea about professional software development and maintenance.

Comment: @dreamlax i removed the * in  `TypeElement ptrElement;` so it's no longer a double pointer, but it still doesn't work... it still doesn't recognize PtrJogo

Comment: @Olaf thanks for the input, i'll try to improve my code from now on, but my problem still stands. Why isn't the type PtrJogo recognized?

Comment: What is in `stackDynamic.h`?

Comment: @kaylum the first block of code on my post. i'll edit the post to point that out

Comment: That's what I thought. So stackDynamic.h includes TreasureHunt.h which includes stackDynamic.h which includes TreasureHunt.h, etc...? Is that the case and if so, do you have include guards in your header files?

Comment: you mean the lines  `#ifndef STACKDYNAMIC_H_INCLUDED` and
`#define STACKDYNAMIC_H_INCLUDED`? the IDE includes them by default, didn't think they would be relevant here( didn't even knew what it was for until now)

Comment: @kaylum i think i understand what the problem is then, they can't include eachother?

Comment: Headers can include each other in general. But you can't have circular dependencies where header1 requires something in header2 and header2 requires something in header1.